# Black rough textures look grey

Tags: texturing, color

So, I'm still new to Blender (3 mos.) and I'm taking on my biggest project yet by modeling a vintage motorcycle. I'm noticing that if I have a black object (in this case the motorcycle tire) and turn up the "roughness" in the Principled BSDF the black color turns to grey. I want to use an HDRI, so I can't change the ambient color of the world. Is there something I am overlooking? I've tried to make the tire look rough by just using Noise Textures and Bump nodes, but It doesn't seem to help much with the color and the tire still looks too shiny. I've attached a recent rendering. Any help would be appreciated! [image]

Comment: Have you compared your tire and frame to photos of similar bikes with similar lighting?  At least on my monitor, your tire looks pretty good to my eyes.  Also, have you experimented with the specular setting?

Comment: @MartyFouts, Reducing the specular setting does help. I thought I tried every setting in the Principled BSDF, but most not have missed it. I'm not really familiar with what it does (need to research it). I also did look at photos of motorcycles in deserts. I think their tires kept the darkness better than mine, but now with that specular setting, I feel I can get close. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  What you have so far looks very good and I'd like to see a render when you're done.  Maybe post an edit here with an update?

Comment: Will do, but it's going to take a while. I'm learning as I go.

Comment: @MartyFouts, I finished the motorcycle and, as promised, I posted it here: https://blenderartists.org/t/newbies-knucklehead/1365410

Comment: Thank you.  That looks very good.  You just made my day.